# Find and move to a specific cell in a datagridview using textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a program in VB.Net that looks like this:

[image]

It has a lot of data and I have a search module like this:

[image]

Here is the code on how I populate:

```
 Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.2.250;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
    Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select Location,Category,ItemCode,Description,UOM,BegInv,Receiving,AvailableStocks,StockIssuance,EndingStocks,StoretoWarehouse,WarehouseToSup,StockAdjust,TheoCount,PhysicalCount,Variance,Remarks from variance", con1)
    Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    con1.Open()
    adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
    adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
    con1.Close()
    With DataGridView1
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Location"
        .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Category"
        .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Item Code"
        .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Description"
        .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "UOM"
        .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Beg. Inventory"
        .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Receiving"
        .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Available Stocks"
        .Columns(8).HeaderCell.Value = "Stock Issuance"
        .Columns(9).HeaderCell.Value = "Ending Stocks"
        .Columns(10).HeaderCell.Value = "Store to Warehouse"
        .Columns(11).HeaderCell.Value = "Warehouse to Supplier"
        .Columns(12).HeaderCell.Value = "Stock Adjustment"
        .Columns(13).HeaderCell.Value = "Theoretical Qty."
        .Columns(14).HeaderCell.Value = "Physical Count"
        .Columns(15).HeaderCell.Value = "Variance"
        .Columns(16).HeaderCell.Value = "Remarks"
        .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        .Columns.Item(0).Width = 125
        .Columns.Item(1).Width = 102
        .Columns.Item(2).Width = 77
        .Columns.Item(3).Width = 236
        .Columns.Item(4).Width = 53
        .Columns.Item(5).Width = 73
        .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns(5).Frozen = True
    End With
```

Seriously I tried this one but it's not working.

```
TextBox1.Text = ""
Dim FirstValue As Boolean =  True 
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
    If Not FirstValue Then
        TextBox1.Text += ", "
    End If
    TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString()
    FirstValue = False
Next
```

Comment: Yes sure I for got sorry. I will update my post.

Comment: Just go there, I mean the blue selected rows will go there.

Comment: _Just go there_? What if multiple records match your search criteria?

Comment: I think that would not be possible because I will based it in the column `Item Code` that has a Unique data but Im also thinking that the data would complete typed before searching, is it also possible for `like` command in datagridview?

Comment: Since you told it so about the multiple data, is it possible to go to the nearest possible match like the `like` clause

Comment: looking forward in all datagridview columns but if not maybe the column `2` or `Item Code`

Comment: Last question, `Item Code` is unique in your `datagrid` right?

Comment: Yes sir that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself honestly call this the *long approach* because I know there are better answers integrating `LINQ` (not that proficient with `LINQ`)

First, declare this variable in your search form:

```
Public dt as New Datatable
```

Second, declare this in your `Form1` (where your `DataGridView1` is placed),
this will hold the records temporarily before opening your search form:

```
Dim tempdt as New Datatable
```

Then include this code before you set your `DataGridView1` data source.
Right after:

```
...
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
tempdt  = New Datatable
tempdt  = ds1.Tables(0)
...
```

Then, call your search form like this (if you have an existing code, replace it with this):

```
Dim srchForm as New YourSearchFormName
srchForm.dt = tempdt
srchForm.Show()
```

Then include this code in your *Find* button in your search form:

```
    Dim drow() As DataRow
    drow = dt.Select("ItemCode LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' OR Description LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'")
    If drow.Count > 0 Then
        'THIS WILL LOOP THE GRID BASED ON THE RECORDS FOUND BY TXTSEARCH.TEXT
        For Each row As DataRow In drow
            Dim ItemCodeStr As String = row.Item("ItemCode").ToString
            For Each dgrow As DataGridViewRow In Form1.DataGridView1.Rows
                If ItemCodeStr = dgrow.Cells(2).Value.ToString Then
                    dgrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("There are no matches found.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Result")
    End If
```

In this code, I used *ItemCode* and *Description* as the criteria. It will change the backcolor to *Pink* when it meets the search criteria. I used *Pink* because it is my favorite color.

Comment: actually my search module is set on other form `Form2` and I placed the code over there and add the name of the Form where the datagridview is placed

Comment: You should have stated that on the first place -_____-

Comment: OMG im sorry sir :(

Comment: Sir all I can say is I love you hahahaha kidding aside the code is working now and based on the output the row will be colored based on the data searched, but my target here is move to the current cell for example i have a data in the last row and i searched it then the data will move to the last row. I hope its possible. any ways TYSM

Comment: Sir I accept it now, just a little modification sir.

Comment: Okay, what still seems to be the problem?

Comment: Instead of coloring the row use the blue one the and  use it to move to the specific row. for example i have a data in the last row and i searched it then the data will move to the last row. I hope its possible

Comment: Can you post another question regarding that? So that I can see more details?

Comment: Sure no problem sir, I will comment the link here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786871/how-to-move-into-specific-row-cell-in-datagridview-using-textbox-vb-net pls see this one sir